# Why am I getting duplicate records at my output?

Tags: xml, xquery

So I have written an XQuery to find out how many times each of the names occur in my XML document. I can get the result but each name is repeated at the output.  Can't anyone see what went wrong?  Thanks very much for your help. By the way, I'm using IBM DB2 for this.

Code:

```
XQUERY
for $tmp in db2-fn:xmlcolumn('STARMA.STARMA_XML')
for $value in distinct-values($tmp//Star_Chef/Name)
let $count := count($tmp//Star_Chef[Name eq $value])
order by $count descending
return concat($value," ",$count);
```

Output:

```
Gary Lineker 6
Gary Lineker 6
Jamie Oliver 5
Jamie Oliver 5
Gordon Ramsey 4
Amir Khan 4
Gordon Ramsey 4
Amir Khan 4
Edwin Tye 3
Megan Fox 3
Edwin Tye 3
Megan Fox 3
Ellie Dee 2
Ellie Dee 2
Andy Lau 1
Andy Lau 1

  16 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your nested loop.

use

```
let $tmp := db2-fn:xmlcolumn('STARMA.STARMA_XML')
```

OR a single for:

```
for $value  in distinct-values(db2-fn:xmlcolumn('STARMA.STARMA_XML'))
let $count := count($tmp//Star_Chef[Name eq $value])
order by $count descending
return concat($value," ",$count);
```